# Adding a door to water shutoff valve in ceiling

Tags: water, ceiling, valve, outdoorfaucet

I am having my kitchen redone and during demolition, a pipe comes loose and I get water damage in my basement. The contractor fixed the damages and is working on the kitchen now. In the basement ceiling, they did not leave me a lot of room to reach the water shutoff valve to the outdoor faucet. I could nag them to make a bigger hole and put a door in, but is that what it is called? Should I ask for a closeable door or is there a better way to describe it?

I think I could do this myself in an hour. Do I just need a tool for cutting a bigger hole in the drywall and some kind of door? Let me know what I would need to DIY. I would rather them continue working on the kitchen and just knock this out during the weekend.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access door or access panel.

You can buy them in various sizes off the shelf, order more sizes, or do it completely DIY by building a frame around a chunk of drywall (or plywood) with screws if you don't access it often, or with hinges and a latch if you need easier access.

The bought ones may be plastic or metal.